# Mounting iPad filesystem in Linux?

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, uti, mount

Is it possible to mount the core filesystem used on the iPad on to my linux box? There is an application named [DiskAid](http://www.digidna.net/products/diskaid) which does this for Windows and Mac, so it *is* accessible, just a matter of how.

I'm looking for the same sort of functionality as iFile (on jailbroken devices).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want an app that can use the [libmobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/) library. Some possible suggestions in the News section of that page.

Answer (score 1):

Why not jailbreak the iPad and ssh over the wifi to access the filesystem?

Use care when you choose what software to do this, realize you are bypassing the security of iOS and pick good passwords.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt DiskAid (or any tool) gives you proper access to the full file system without a jailbreak. Rather, [judging from the screenshots](http://www.digidna.net/products/diskaid/features/file-sharing-with-iphone-and-ipad-apps), it shows particular sections exposed through APIs.